# How to pass environment variables to kubectl create deployment command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How to pass environment variables to kubectl create deployment command?

I'm trying to pass environment variable to kubectl create deployment command with below syntax

```
kubectl create deployment  nginx-deployment --replicas=2  --env="HOSTNAME=dev.example.com" --env="KEY=randomkey1456" --env="PORT_NUMBER=5601" --image=nginx
```

It's throwing below error message saying `--env` as an unknown flag

```
error: unknown flag: --env
```

Similar syntax is working with below `kubectl run` command successfully

```
kubectl run  nginx-deployment --env="HOSTNAME=dev.example.com" --env="KEY=randomkey1456" --env="PORT_NUMBER=5601" --image=nginx
```

So what's the right way to pass an environment variable to `kubectl create deployment` imperative command?

Comment: You're formatting it not proper, you shouldn't have any space between `env=` and the key-value pairs. if you run `kubectl run --help | grep env` you can see suggestions

Comment: updated question with proper spacing.  environment variables passed through ```kubectl run``` is working. But the same environment variables passed through ```kubectl create deployment``` are not working.

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd write the YAML file, check it into source control, and use `kubectl apply -f` to submit it to the cluster.  Tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh) can take dynamic parameters injected at deploy time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
kubectl create deployment nginx-deployment --replicas=2 --image=nginx
kubectl set env deployment/nginx-deployment \
      HOSTNAME=dev.example.com \
      KEY=randomkey1456 \
      PORT_NUMBER=5601
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be appreciated  to add additional context explaining the code ‍.

Answer (score 0):

The `kubectl create` command does not support this. The best you can do is lean on it for generating a resource, patch it, and apply:

```bash
kubectl create deployment nginx-deployment --replicas=2 --image=nginx --dry-run=client -o json | \
jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env |= [{name: "HOSTNAME", value: "dev.example.com"}]' | \
kubectl apply -f -
```

You may want to use jq's argument processing features to move the arguments out of the jq expression. For example:

```bash
jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env |=
  [$ARGS.positional[] | split("=") | {name: .[0], value: .[1]}]' \
  --args HOSTNAME=dev.example.com
```